# divide every element by every other to create a matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab

If I have a vector of numbers `A = 1 2 3`

Is it possible to create a matrix with

```
A = [ 1/1 1/2 1/3;
      1/2 2/2 2/3;
      1/3 2/3 3/3;]

I naively tried 

%%
a = 1:3;

aa = a./a(:); %This is what I naively tried

A = [ 1/1 1/2 1/3;
      1/2 2/2 2/3;
      1/3 2/3 3/3;]
```

aa was what I naively tried

Comment: So... `A = min(aa,aa.');`?

Comment: Yes! Thanks make it a answer and I will accept

Comment: In your example `A(2,3)` should be `2/3` not `3/3` right ?

Comment: yes sorry I will change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need

```
A = min(aa,aa.');
```

where `aa` is computed as in your question.

---

Mostly for fun, you could also abuse [`pdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) (Statistics Toolbox) for this:

```
A = exp(-squareform(pdist(log(a(:)))));
```

where `a = 1:3` as in your question.

Comment: 100k, congratulations ;)